# Plot the sparsity of a dataframe of dummy columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to visualize the sparsity of a dataframe which contains columns of `0`s and `1`s (in total, is 90% of `0`s and 10% of `1`s ).

So far, I've tried the following:

```
sparse_df = df[binary_feat_cols].astype(pd.SparseDtype("int", 0))
sparse_df.sparse.density
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.spy(sparse_df, markersize=1);
```

And

```
sparse_matrix = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(df[binary_feat_cols].to_numpy())
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.spy(sparse_matrix, markersize=1);
```

In both cases, I get that the image shows. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

EDIT: I've just realized that it is something related to the shape of the matrix because I've tried this example:

```
x = np.random.randn(910, 51)
x[15, :] = 0.
x[:, 40] = 0.
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.spy(x, markersize = 5)
```

and I get this new plot:
[image]

So, the problem should be that the dataframe has ~900K rows and 50 columns, and that cannot be plotted?

Answer (score 0):

I checked here [matplotlib.pyplot.spy](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.spy.html#matplotlib.pyplot.spy) and I saw the `aspect` parameter:

> aspect{'equal', 'auto', None} or float, default: 'equal'
> The aspect ratio of the Axes. This parameter is particularly relevant for images since it determines whether data pixels are square.
> This parameter is a shortcut for explicitly calling Axes.set_aspect. See there for further details.
> 'equal': Ensures an aspect ratio of 1. Pixels will be square.
> 'auto': The Axes is kept fixed and the aspect is adjusted so that the data fit in the Axes. In general, this will result in
> non-square pixels.
> None: Use rcParams["image.aspect"] (default: 'equal').

So, doing `plt.spy(sparse_df, markersize=1, aspect = 'auto')` has solved my issue. Thanks!